# fortawesome/react-fontawesome package change icon onclick

Tags: reactjs, onclick, icons, font-awesome

I have the following icon in my code:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon id="star" onClick={this.handleClick} icon={hollowstar} size="lg" />
```

I need the icon to change from hollowstar to solidstar onclick. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import { faStar as fasFaStar } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faStar as farFaStar } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';

// ...

const [star, setStar] = useState(farFaStar);

// ...

<FontAwesomeIcon
  onClick={() => {
    setStar(fasFaStar);
  }}
  icon={star}
  // Other props...
/>
```

So in the code we import the same star icon with different styles like described in the documentation here: https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome#how-do-i-import-the-same-icon-from-two-different-styles.

Since the icon is just an object you can save it to the state and update the state to the other icon inside an onClick function.

For clarity, I've used a functional component here.